# React: 'Maximum update depth exceeded' with FullCalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, gatsby

I am using FullCalendar for react and I am struggling with the state.... It returns this message :

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I removed all the unnecessary parts of the code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";

const Top = () => {

  // Calendar info stored in state
  const [calendarEvents, setCalendarEvents] = useState([]);

  // method to retrieve dates
  const getEventsForThisMonth = () => {
    const events = [];
    events.push({
      title: "test",
      date: '2021-03-25',
    });
    return events;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventsCollected = getEventsForThisMonth();
    setCalendarEvents(eventsCollected);
  }, [calendarEvents]);

  return (
    <>
      <FullCalendar
        defaultView="dayGridMonth"
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        events={calendarEvents}
        locale="ja"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Top;
```

Let me know if you want me to provide more information.
Any feedback/ idea is welcome !
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you useEffect has the dependency of state when the useEffect itself changes the state.

When your useEffect runs -> It changes the state -> The state changed will trigger the useEffect to run -> ... 
It causes an infinite loop. 
To fix it, change the dependency of the useEffect base on your need. Perhaps put the setCalendarEvents inside the getEventsForThisMonth function and use this function in onChange event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It definitely makes sense. But I don't have any onchange, can you  check again the code ? I m just passing an array of events to my component as props.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, you are triggering a `useEffect` with a `calendarEvents` dependency, which sets the state of the calendar events (`setCalendarEvents`) again, which also triggers again the `useEffect`, and so on... creating an infinite loop.

If want to avoid it keeping your workaround, you may want to set the events inside the the first time, with a `useEffect` with empty `deps` (`[]`):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";

const Top = () => {

  // Calendar info stored in state
  const [calendarEvents, setCalendarEvents] = useState([]);

  // method to retrieve dates
  const getEventsForThisMonth = () => {
    const events = [];
    events.push({
      title: "test",
      date: '2021-03-25',
    });
    return events;
  };


  useEffect(()=>{
    const eventsCollected = getEventsForThisMonth();
    setCalendarEvents(eventsCollected);
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <FullCalendar
        defaultView="dayGridMonth"
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        events={calendarEvents}
        locale="ja"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Top;
```